# Как добавить C++ библиотеку к Android Ndk проекту?

Tags: c++, android, cmake, android-ndk

Есть прекрасная библиотека libpcap.a она скомпилирована для android в такие папки: arm64-v8a1, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64 там еще папки для api (https://github.com/seladb/libpcap-android). Как мне эту библиотеку добавить к проекту android NDK чтобы пользоваться ей в С++ коде?
Сперва я погуглил попробывал по простому скопировать все в папку libs и в модуле build.grudle добавил:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
```

Но это не помогло в С++ при подключении `#include <pcap.h>` писало не найдено.
Я подумал надо в CMake файл эти библиотеки добавить. Но там чего я вообще не понимаю. Я пробовал добавлять такое но конечно ничего не компилировалось:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include)
find_library(LIBPCAP_LIB libpcap "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/lib")
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBPCAP_LIB})
```

Я незнаком с C++ и CMAKE, поэтому перенес библиотеки в директорию где находится CMAKE файл, потому что CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR это явно директория где он находится. Но увы ничего не работает.
Немного дополню я вынимал libpcap.a и ставил в начало пути libs/libpcap.a и потом другие папки, чтобы наверняка все видело, но увы не работает.